# How do I read claims from my Oauth token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, claims-based-identity

I made a Security Token Service that connects to my identity store and returns an OAuth2 token with claims if valid. I'm using the Thinktecture.IdentityServer for this. Now I can pass the token to my API, but how do I use this token in my web services to make sure that it returns data that is filtered on the basis of the appropriate claims in the token?

I think some samples might exist here: https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/tree/master/Samples/Web%20API but I'm not certain I understand what is happening here. Can someone please write a GET that parses identity claims from the jwt token and returns a set of the claims?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think the answer can be found [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/05/25/json-web-token-jwt-support-in-thinktecture-identitymodel/), but these [integration tests](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/blob/master/src/Tests/Integration%20Tests/OAuth2Tests.cs) were much more helpful.