# How to extract and get a claim from token?

Tags: c#, token, access-token, claims-based-identity, claims

I've been looking for an exact answer but it seems most answers are client call and out of the scope.

Question: I already have an access token access token. How to get a claim using c# code given an access token ONLY?

I think: Below are the same questions but no answers i think fits.

[How to get the claims out of a authenticated SecurityToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174039/how-to-get-the-claims-out-of-a-authenticated-securitytoken)

[How do I read claims from my Oauth token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441400/how-do-i-read-claims-from-my-oauth-token)

Comment: For clarification: You want to, on the server, identify a user's claims given only his bearer token?

Comment: yes would that be possible?

Comment: What about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357054/return-more-info-to-the-client-using-oauth-bearer-tokens-generation-and-owin-in

Comment: It is. I've tried to decode my token in https://jwt.io/ and that includes.

Comment: I edited my last comment before you posted your answer - take a look a the link in that comment, that might help you.

Comment: Can you access Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims?

Answer (score 6):

Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

The access token is just base64 encoded JSON. You can parse the token as follows

```
        string token =
            "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ";
        var parts = token.Split('.');
        var decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(parts[1]);
        var part = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
        var jwt = JObject.Parse(part);
        var name = jwt["name"].Value<string>();
```

***UPDATE***

1. Parsing access token on the client is not recommended, access token
   should be parsed only on the resource server.
2. You must validate the access token on the resource server to make
   sure that token has not tampered on the way.
3. Most of the time you dont need to parse token as above, Just use a
   recommended JWT library that does both validation and parsing. e.g.

   `app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());`

Answer (score 0):

rawel provided a very handy sample! One small problem I encountered were the namespaces, I had to use (just to make this easier to find for the next person, since I cannot post comments yet):

```
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29997093)